# Connecting AWS with Ruby on Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have gone through a number of questions trying to resolve my issues, but every time I solve one another pops up.

A lot of answers seem outdated.

Can anyone give me a simple break down on how to connect an RoR application to AWS to allow users to download files from a bucket?

I feel that the majority of my errors have stemmed from poor configuration on my part. The AWS documentation hasnt been much help.

Answer (score 0):

Try
[AWS SDK for Ruby - Version 1](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/index.html)

```
require 'aws-sdk'

access_key_id = ACCESS_KEY_ID
secret_access_key = SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

aws3 = AWS::S3.new(access_key_id: access_key_id, secret_access_key: secret_access_key)

bucket = aws3.buckets['BUCKET_NAME']

# get data thru iteration
bucket.objects.each do |object|
  puts object.key
  puts object.read
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Could you explain how to use environment variables?

Comment: do you mean, environment variables from your rails application?